# Issue with Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.user.props when trying to add a shared Property sheet in Visual C++ 2012

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to build a common Property sheets in a Visual C++ 2012 solution with many projects, following steps described in http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsproject/archive/2009/06/23/inherited-properties-and-property-sheets.aspx.

I'm trying to disable Compiler Optimisation for my Release Build in all the projects. Please let me know if there is a more straight forward way to do this as I don't want to edit each project manually.

I managed to create my commons.props property sheets for my Release build. The issue arises when I try to modify the evaluation order to get `Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.user` evaluated last. I get the following error message:

```
Could not find the import for 
"..\..\..\..\Users\aguinard\AppData\Local\Microsoft\MSBuild\v4.0\
Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.user.props" in an import group with label 
"PropertySheets" and condition "'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'==
'Release|Win32'" in the file "C:\cef\chromiumv27\src\cef\libcef.vcxproj".
```

The path to the `Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.user.props` seems to be valid.

Not sure if it helps, but below are my `Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.user.props` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets">
  </ImportGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Label="UserMacros" />
  <PropertyGroup />
  <ItemDefinitionGroup>
    <ClCompile>
      <Optimization>Disabled</Optimization>
      <AdditionalOptions />
    </ClCompile>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <ItemGroup />
</Project>
```

and my commons.props:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" />
  <PropertyGroup Label="UserMacros" />
  <PropertyGroup />
  <ItemDefinitionGroup />
  <ItemGroup />
</Project>
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty undiagnosable from the provided info.  You are also not exactly ahead by having to give each project a property sheet, that's actually a lot more work than editing the setting for each project.

There is a better way, simply select all the projects in the solution first.  Select the first project in the solution and Shift + Click the last one so they are all selected.  Right-click + Properties and change the setting.

Comment: Thanks - this helps. I tried to change setting on the whole solution before with no luck. Selecting all Projects works (provided that I first unselect the ones with only *.h files)